# How can I implement UIDocument.h?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to import UIDocument.h into my app delegate file and when I do all I get is implementation errors. My code is:

```
     #import UIDocument.h
```

I'm still pretty new to Objective-C programing so I hope you don't mind a basic question. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import <UIKit/UIDocument.h>
```

with the < and > bits and no spaces in between.  :-)

UIDocument.h will only work on iOS 5 apps, b.t.w.

Comment: @Tyler - You shouldn't need to explicitly import the header for UIDocument.  If you simply import UIKit: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`, you will get all UIKit controls.